# Can you help me to understand this thevenin circuit's mesh?

Tags: thevenin, mesh-analysis, loop-analysis

[image]

Why didn't we involve the 4 Ohm resistor while doing the mesh i2 ?

Comment: A mistake? Slip of the pen?

Comment: I have no idea, I thought maybe it's because that part is an open circuit, so

Comment: No, what is the answer for the Thevenin voltage?  And \$V_\phi\$ is?

Comment: Vϕ is 20V, Voc is 120V ,i source(when you make it a short circuit)=40 ohm, Rth is 3 ohm, Vth is 60 Volt

Comment: I meant,  what is the "parameter" for \$V_\phi = 4\Omega \times I_1 \times  What\$

Comment: Im sorry I still don't understand but Vϕ =4(i1-i2) , but i assume you already know this, I didn't get the parameter part though

Comment: But \$V_\phi\$ is a Voltage controlled Voltage source, so you need to know the "control parameter" value (VCVS gain).

Comment: And the second mesh equation should look like this: \$-V_\phi + 8\Omega I_2+4\Omega(I_2 - I_1)=0\$

Comment: Yes, I think so, too. However the solution was different but as you said it might be a mistake, so thank you

Comment: Also noticed that the control voltage (in blue) for your VCVS is equal to \$V_\phi = 4\Omega I_1\$

Answer (score 0):

Your first loop equation is correct. For the dependent source, only the i1 current needs to be taken into consideration.
We can use the outer loop for finding Vth.

[image: eqns]